# How to remove empty space in a div element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here I am providing a screenshot and I outlined the area I wanted to collapse all the way to just right after the last blue buttom, touching it. I outlined the area I wanted to collapse in red. Is there a specific class that will let me do that?

Ty

[image: Collapse]

code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-primary col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Label -->
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btn-block" id='invoicelabel'><strong>Invoice CP</strong>
      </button>

      <!-- Invoice CP -->
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-vertical col-md-3 test2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Total Amount</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Duplicate</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Clear</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Currency</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" disabled>.</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" disabled>.</button>
      </div>
      <table class="table table-condensed">
        <tbody class="col-md-10 test pull-right">
          <tr>
            <td class="default" width="20%">
              <input type="text" class="btn btn-default btn-sm col-sm-12 floatright" placeholder="Pieces">
            </td>
            <td class="default" width="35%">
              <input type="text" class="btn btn-default btn-sm col-sm-12 floatright" placeholder="Unit Price">
            </td>
            <td class="default" width="45%">
              <input type="text" class="btn btn-default btn-sm col-sm-12 floatright" placeholder="Line Amount">
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="default" width="20%">
              <input type="text" class="btn btn-default btn-sm col-sm-12 floatright" placeholder="Pieces">
            </td>
            <td class="default" width="35%">
              <input type="text" class="btn btn-default btn-sm col-sm-12 floatright" placeholder="Unit Price">
            </td>
            <td class="default" width="45%">
              <input type="text" class="btn btn-default btn-sm col-sm-12 floatright" placeholder="Line Amount">
            </td>
          </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi there. Could you please clarify "*collapse all the way to just right after the last blue buttom, touching it*"? There's no content, so there's nothing to collapse. Are you looking to extend the sidebar so that it takes up the full height of the page?

Comment: Just the HTML is not enough. Anyway, by the looks of things it seems you are using flexbox, so just remove that. If not, then post the relevant CSS. Make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and/or use the snippets.

Comment: If the browser is longer than content you get white

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the CSS `height` property of the `.test` or `.test2`. Probably it is set to a specific value. If you leave it blank, the area will fit to the content.